# How to collect chat history in telegram and identify the most active chat participants?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I want to collect chat history in Telegram and upload the data to Excel for further analysis. I need to collect user id, date of sending, message text (if the message contains media then just specify the type of voice message, circle and so on), I would like to collect all messages from the chat but while experimenting I have set a limit of 1000 last messages. But the code below doesn't work saying that it doesn't see the chat (I am an administrator) and did I specify the delays correctly so that I don't get blocked by Telegram?

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import pandas as pd
import asyncio
import time

api_id = '******'  # substitute with your API ID
api_hash = '********'  # substitute with your API HASH
phone = '+*******'  # substitute with your phone number

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

data = {
    'user_id' : [],
    'message_timestamp' : [],
    'message_text' : [],
    'message_media_type' : []
}

async def collect_messages(client):
    chat = await client.get_input_entity('-*******')  # substitute with actual chat id

    # Initialize variable to store last message id
    last_msg_id = None
    limit = 100  # Fetch 100 messages at a time

    for _ in range(10):  # 10*100=1000 messages
        # Getting messages from the chat
        messages = await client.get_messages(chat, limit=limit, max_id=last_msg_id)
        time.sleep(1)  # To respect rate limits

        for message in messages:
            user_id = message.sender_id
            message_timestamp = message.date
            message_text = message.text

            if message.media is not None:
                # Media information without downloading the file
                message_media_type = message.media.__class__.__name__
            else:
                message_media_type = None

            data['user_id'].append(user_id)
            data['message_timestamp'].append(message_timestamp)
            data['message_text'].append(message_text)
            data['message_media_type'].append(message_media_type)

        # Save the id of the last message to fetch next set of messages
        last_msg_id = messages[-1].id

# Run the async function
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(collect_messages(client))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel('telegram_messages.xlsx', index=False)
```

I tried the code above but the program does not find the chat I specified

Answer (score 1):

```py
chat = await client.get_input_entity('-*******')
```

This makes me suspect you're using a string for a channel identifier. Identifiers are `int`, not `str`. Remove the quotes:

```py
chat = await client.get_input_entity(-*******)
```

Note that the identifier must be in Telethon's cache for this to work.

A better option would be to use `client.iter_dialogs` (in v1 of the library) to find the right chat, and then `client.iter_messages`.

`client.iter_messages` already automatically sleeps a second every 100 messages. You can leave out the limit to fetch all messages in the chat. It's a lot easier than having to do it in batches of 100 manually with `get_messages`.

Comment: Yes, this is really better, thank you very much for the advice. Can you also tell me what the problem is that when I run the code, I log out of all running telegram sessions. I'm afraid because of this I can get banned due to frequent login attempts

Comment: It's a known issue and unfortunately not something Telethon can solve https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/4051.